# javascript: draw an image underground and save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, cesiumjs

I am working on Censiumjs, which is a javascript map library. I want to make a heatmap from json data and render it on the map.

Currently my idea is to draw a heatmap on a hidden canvas using a heatmap javascript plugin, then save the canvas as an image file, and finally render the image on the map.

However I found that I cannot draw on a hidden canvas. So I am wondering how I can draw an image underground and save it while loading the map?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Canvas can be on top of the image, overlaying while drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [offscreen rendering](http://devbutze.blogspot.com/2014/02/html5-canvas-offscreen-rendering.html)

```
function main(){            
        // here we create an OFFSCREEN canvas
        var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        offscreenCanvas.width = 300px;
        offscreenCanvas.height = 300px;
        var context = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

        // draw something into the OFFSCREEN context
        context.fillRect(10,10,290,290);
        // ...

    }
```